# Ubuntu freezing and requires a reboot (Firefox issue?)

Tags: firefox, freeze

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo x220t thinkpad. Intel i5-2520 cpu, 4gb ram, Intel HD graphics 3000, kernel Linux 5.13.0-35-generic. All my software is up to date I believe.

After working on my computer for an hour or two, it will invariably freeze and won't respond to my keyboard, and I'll need to do a hard reset. I think it is caused by Firefox because after switching to Edge yesterday, it hasn't frozen since. I can go back to using Firefox and see what happens today but I don't necessarily want to use my computer for two more hours right now.

I'm wondering if there's likely to be some logs or info on my computer that I can look at or show here that might indicate what has been causing the freezing?

Comment: If the problem is indeed time based as you have hypothesized, could it be overheating? I suggest that you keep up a resource monitor to see if anything is hogging resources around the time the problem starts.

Comment: Agreed, using `htop` really helps in a situation like this.  You can see which resource is using CPU, memory, etc. and how much is in use. If this is a RAM issue, how much swap do you have and what is swappiness set to? Increasing swappiness and/or swap space can help if RAM is the issue. If it's high CPU/heat, you might be able to run some commands to better detect your sensors.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` (after working for an hour or two) and `swapon -s` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and a screenshot of `top`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.